# xk6 failed to build if "xk6-output-prometheus-remote" extension is added with another one

Tags: prometheus, grafana, performance-testing, k6

I am trying to build a k6 binary using xk6 to add the extensions that I need. First of all, I downloaded the latest version of xk6:

`go install go.k6.io/xk6/cmd/xk6@latest`

After that, I have the xk6 executable, so I will add only the "xk6-output-prometheus-remote" extension:

```
./xk6 build --with github.com/grafana/xk6-output-prometheus-remote@latest
xk6 has now produced a new k6 binary which may be different than the command on your system path!
```

As you can see, everything is fine if I add just that extension. But now, I will add the xk6-kafka extension, so I type the next:

`./xk6 build --with github.com/grafana/xk6-output-prometheus-remote@latest --with github.com/mostafa/xk6-kafka@latest`

And I get the next error complaining about the xk6-output-prometheus-remote:

```
# github.com/grafana/xk6-output-prometheus-remote/pkg/remotewrite
../../pkg/mod/github.com/grafana/xk6-output-prometheus-remote@v0.2.3/pkg/remotewrite/remotewrite.go:173:13: t.Total undefined (type *"go.k6.io/k6/metrics".TrendSink has no field or method Total)
../../pkg/mod/github.com/grafana/xk6-output-prometheus-remote@v0.2.3/pkg/remotewrite/trend.go:28:23: undefined: metrics.NewTrendSink
2023/08/30 10:45:35 [INFO] Cleaning up temporary folder: .../go/bin/buildenv_2023-08-30-1045.725323668
2023/08/30 10:45:35 [FATAL] exit status 1
```

If a try to execute a normal xk6 build with other extensions, I have no issues:

`./xk6 build --with github.com/mostafa/xk6-kafka@latest --with github.com/mostafa/xk6-sql@latest --with github.com/mostafa/xk6-output-influxdb@latest`

And again, everything is fine.

I tried to look if it extension has something special to install it but i couldn't find anything.

I also tried to build the k6 binary using containers as the oficial documentation but the output is the same using a container.

Please, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

As of v0.42.0, you no longer need to compile in the xk6-output-prometheus-remote extension. It is included in the k6 release binary as an experimental module by default. So, in your example, where you are excluding `--with github.com/grafana/xk6-output-prometheus-remote@latest`, you still have the Prometheus Remote Write capability.

See https://k6.io/docs/results-output/real-time/prometheus-remote-write/ for the most up-to-date usage.